# Error after installing but not in development system

Tags: c#, winforms, localdb

I recently created a database restoring module in my project using the following code

```
        string cbdfilename = "C:\\Users\\Public\\Bbcon.bak";
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;");
        string sql = "Restore database @DBNAME from Disk = @FILENAME With Move 'BB'";
        SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
        string database = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, @"BbCon.mdf");
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME", database);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FILENAME", cbdfilename);
        con.Open();
        try
        {
            MessageBox.Show(cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString());

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Backup DB failed" + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
            con.Dispose();
        }
```

i database i restord sucessfully when i debugged using visual studio so i created a installation file using clickonce and installed on clients system but it show an error

[image]

Comment: The error there clearly says your db is in use. Try killing all connections before you try to restore the db.

Comment: how is that can be done

Comment: can helpme to find correct path to database file using Appdomain

Comment: mate, the path is correct, the db is  simply in use?